# Does FileReader and FileWriter uses an internal buffer?

Tags: java, file-io

I know that the `FileReader` and `FileWriter` reads and writes characters one-by-one. So, it should me making a system call everytime.

But my question is that, **does it internally use a buffer to optimize IO performance?**

Otherwise, reading an array of characters like here,

```
public int read(char[] cbuf, int offset, int length)
```

would require a system call for each of the characters being read.

Or writing a portion of String like here,

```
public void write(String str, int off,int len)
```

would be quite heavy isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileReader` and `FileWriter` derive from `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`. The implementations of these do use buffers internally to make conversions between bytes and characters more efficient, for example OpenJDK uses 8kB buffers (see the [StreamDecoder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/nio/cs/StreamDecoder.java#StreamDecoder.0DEFAULT_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE) and [StreamEncoder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/nio/cs/StreamEncoder.java#StreamEncoder.0DEFAULT_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE) classes). The API specification gives you no guarantees though and recommends that you use `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` for IO performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate a bit on ' to make conversions between bytes and characters more efficient"?

Comment: It's slightly more efficient to convert a bunch of data in a single method call than to make several method calls for every character. The overhead of method calls adds up when you have gigabytes of data to process.

Answer (score 1):

No, but they respectively use `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`, which both have buffers.

Answer (score 0):

No Aritra. It doesnt use internal buffer. That job is done by BufferedReader. BufferedReader internally buffers the reading of characters. It reads text from a character input stream/file system, and stores it into a buffer. So when a user make a request for next character it will return that character from the buffer , not from the file system. 
You can wrap BufferedReader around FileReader  :

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
```